# UWP : How to get a list of all the text file names from a sub folder of Documents folder

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-10

Learning to develop for windows 10. I'm trying to access a Sub-folder inside the documents folder and list all the text file names that are present in the subfolder. Please help.

Comment: What have you tried so far and where exactly are you stuck?

Comment: @germi Actually i'm porting a winform app to UWP.Here is the winform code.
string appPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath);
            DirectoryInfo filesPath = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\Typing\");
            FileInfo[] Files = filesPath.GetFiles("*.txt");
            string fileName = "";
            int fileNum = Files.Length;
            for (int i = 0; i < fileNum; i++)
            {
                fileName = "" + Files[i];
             }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to access Documents folder, you can use **FolderPicker** or **KnownFolders.DocumentsLibrary** method.

About FolderPicker, you need to access folders by interacting with a picker, but you can directly choose the folder you want to. About `KnownFolders.DocumentsLibrary` method, you need to add extra broadFileSystemAccess capability and  allow your app to access file system in settings.
​

```
//FolderPicker
var folderPicker = new Windows.Storage.Pickers.FolderPicker();
folderPicker.SuggestedStartLocation = Windows.Storage.Pickers.PickerLocationId.DocumentsLibrary;
folderPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add("*");
Windows.Storage.StorageFolder subFolder = await folderPicker.PickSingleFolderAsync();

//KnownFolders.DocumentsLibrary
//StorageFolder Myfolder = KnownFolders.DocumentsLibrary;
//StorageFolder subFolder = await Myfolder.GetFolderAsync("YouSubFolder");
​
List<string> fileTypeFilter = new List<string>();
fileTypeFilter.Add(".txt");
QueryOptions queryOptions = new QueryOptions(Windows.Storage.Search.CommonFileQuery.OrderByName, fileTypeFilter);
StorageFileQueryResult queryResult = subFolder.CreateFileQueryWithOptions(queryOptions);
var files = await queryResult.GetFilesAsync();
foreach (var file in files)
{
    string name = file.Name;
}
```